# Array of inputs Angular 7

Tags: arrays, angular

I have a Array and any input, I would like when submit get all values this array in the inputs

```
<div *ngIf="this.exercises.length != 0" >
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let exercise of exercises; let i = index">
    <div class="col lg-3">
      {{ exercise.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="serie">
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="repetition"> {{i}}
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="weigth">{{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

how can get all values in the inputs ?

[image]

Comment: Your best bet is to look into `FormArray`. This allows a dynamic number of `FormControl` to be captured.

Comment: Similar to this one https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArrayName ?

Comment: Your requirements seems to be unclear. Do you want to show array values in input? Can you not use `value` attribute on input to show ?

Comment: Have a look at this guide: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays

Comment: yes each array item has a entry

Comment: @WillAlexander I'll trying implement this guide I'll be back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FormGroup` like that

```
<div *ngIf="this.exercises.length != 0" >
  <form [formGroup]="itemForm" >
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let exercise of exercises; let i = index">
    <div class="col lg-3">
      {{ exercise.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="serie{{i}}">
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="repetitionserie{{i}}"> {{i}}
    </div>
    <div class="col lg-3">
      <input matInput type="text" placeholder="0" formControlName="weigthserie{{i}}">{{i}}
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Secondly,add property for `FormGroup` name as itemForm and whenever you want in your ts file call the value of form like

```
itemForm: FormGroup;
...

ngOnInit(){
  let index=0;
  this.exercices.forEach(controlName =>
    this.itemForm.addControl('serie' + index, new FormControl(''));
    this.itemForm.addControl('repetitionserie' + index, new FormControl(''));
    this.itemForm.addControl('weigthserie' + index, new FormControl(''));
    index++;
  );
}

onSubmit(){
   let formValue = this.itemForm.value;
   ....
}
```

Comment: I get this error for all inputs ROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'serie0' ... ?

Comment: I'm sorry friend, but I'm use this way this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [ '', Validators.required ],  
      serie: [ '', Validators.required ],  
      repetition: [ '', Validators.required ],  
      weigth: [ '', Validators.required ],  
    });

Comment: can I implement this way ?

Comment: Yes you can implement your form builder

Comment: @ahmetical, why don't use a FormArray?

Comment: @Eliseo also it can be used, but i didnt know all property of the form

Comment: Thanks @ahmeticat now it's work fine i did some modifications and its ok

Answer (score 0):

Rafael, think in FormArray

First create a function that return a formGroup, and a variable that was a FormArray

formArray:FormArray;

```
createGroup(data:any)
{
   data=data || {serie:0,repetition:0,weigth:0}
   return new FormGroup({
       serie:new FormControl(data.serie),
       repetition:new FormControl(data.repetition),
       weigth:new FormControl(data.weigth),
   }))
}
```

second in a ngOnInit create the formArray using your array exercises. You can loop over exercises and use push or use map

```
ngOnInit()
{
    this.formArray=new FormArray(this.exercises.map(x=>{
        return this.createGroup(null)
    })
}
```

You simple iterate over FormArray.controls.(*)

```
<form *ngIf="formArray" [formGroup]="formArray" (submit)="submit(formArray)">
    <div *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls;let i=index" [formGroup]="group">
        {{exercises[i]}}
        <input formControlName="serie">
        <input formControlName="repetition">
        <input formControlName="weigth">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

You can see the code in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rznfef)

(*)Yes, there're severals ways to iterate over a FormArray. The clasic is a FormArray in a FormGroup and we use

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <div formArrayName="formArray">
      <div *ngFor="let group of formGroup.get('formArray').controls; let i = index;"
           [formGroupName]="i">
           <input formControlName="...">
           <input formControlName="...">
             ...
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

But if we has only a formArray, we can simply loop over formArray.controls and indicate that the [formGroup] is the variable over we iterate. We are replacing `[formGroupName]="i"` by `[formGroup]="group"`